# How do I get Django to delete files when I remove a model object when using Django 1.9?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to get Django version 1.9 to delete the file corresponding to a FileField in my model when I remove the model. My first try was based on the [delete signals as explained in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14310174/214742) but that does not seem to work from Django 1.8 and onwards. Another answer pointed me in the direction of [Django-cleanup](https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup) but it does not work for me either (could it be that it uses the same approach internally?). I have also tried the [post delete signal approach explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33081018/214742) but the method never triggered. So what is the new way of doing this, any approach that deletes the file when deleting the model is fine to me.

Comment: Your question is too broad but see if this answer helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/37127220/267540

Answer (score 1):

I went with the following workaround in my view:

```
@login_required
def deleteDataset(request, pk):
    instance = DatasetModel.objects.defer('filecontent').get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        path = instance.filecontent.path
        instance.delete()
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            os.remove(path)

        return redirect(main)
    else:
        return redirect(main)
```

But I still would like to find a better solution since I would prefer to keep the view as short as possible